# How to make a predetermined polygon (circle) from 4 coordinates, the radius and center Longitude and Latitude in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, polygon, geometry, coordinates

I know how to make a predetermined polygon in OpenLayers (see below).

Please have a look at http://studio.netnrg.co.za/dev/rnd/blake.loizides/openlayers

```
var feature2 = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
  OpenLayers.Geometry.fromWKT("POLYGON((-120.828125 -50.3515625, -80.1875 -80.0078125, -40.40625 -20.4140625, -120.828125 -50.3515625))"
  )
);
vectors.addFeatures([feature2]);
```

I have made an edit circle (40 points in OpenLayers) (my client wanted to see a circle on the map for zones).

The problem I have is that I can only store the following details and not the 40 points or coordinates or vertices to make a circle in OpenLayers. I can only **STORE 4 COORDINATES**.

In the database I store the bounds top bottom left and right (bottom: -29.054153382197, left: 23.782779686138, right: 23.79286499053, top: -29.044068077805) I will replace the coordinates with the ones in my database.

The radius (525.627982303084)

And the center Longitude and Latitude (lon=23.787822338334,lat=-29.049110730001)

Now I made some calculations below.

My question is how do I now recreate a (circle) with the information I have above that is stored in my database?

I know how to get data from my database and display it on the map, what I don't know is how to make a circle if I can't store the 40 points and only have the radius, the bounds, and the center Lon/Lat to make a circle.

Please if anyone can help me I would be greatly appreciative.

I only want a circle for the look and for no other reason.

[image: My Calculations]

[image: Circle from OpenLayers]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to openlayers but this helped me you only need a center point (long lat) and a radius don't forget the function createGeodesicPolygon

[Creating vector features onload in OpenLayers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22850/creating-vector-features-onload-in-openlayers/22860#22860)

there is a link to a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4S5Ke/1/)

```
var origin = "new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(Long Lat)"; 
//then set the radius here 
var polygon = createGeodesicPolygon(origin, RADIUS, 60, 0, map.getProjectionObject())
```

hope that helps

Comment: Yes, and for origin use the center point of your bounds by doing a [myBounds.getCenterLonLat()](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.getCenterLonLat). example: `var originLonLat = myBounds.getCenterLonLat(); var origin = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(originLonLat.lon originLonLat.lat);`

Comment: Here's a working example of it using your example bounds from database. http://jsfiddle.net/4S5Ke/5/

Comment: And this one with your example radius: http://jsfiddle.net/4S5Ke/6/

Comment: Thanks Holly and Thanks CaptDragon that helped me alot . Thanks so much